# supervisord with Upstart always hangs

Tags: upstart, supervisord

I'm trying to start supervisord with Upstart. The Upstart job is very simple and traditional (start on, stop on, author description, respawn, exec).

I've tried running *supervisord* in the foreground ("-n") and omitting the "expect" stanza from the Upstart job. The *start* and *stop* both hang.

I've tried running *supervisord* as a daemon (its default mode), and setting "expect" to both "fork" and "daemon" (and "stop", in desperate attempt). *start* and *stop* both hang.

The Upstart log doesn't display any entries from my attempts.

The only way that I can get it to start is to write the job and restart the system. It always starts properly. But, the command always blocks when I try to manually stop and start it.

I'm very familiar with Upstart infrastructure and configuration. Does anyone have any advice?